# How to convert RDD into Dataframe with Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have an RDD below, which I have received from a client. How can I convert this RDD into a Dataframe?

```
["Row(Moid=2, Tripid='11', Tstart='2007-05-28 08:53:14.040', Tend='2007-05-28 08:53:16.040', Xstart='9738.73', Ystart='103.246', Xend='9743.73', Yend='114.553')"]
```

Comment: Do you have only one element in your list, enclosed by double quotes `".."`? Normally if you have a `list` like `list_rows = [Row(...), Row(...)...]`, without `Row()` being enclosed by double quotes, then after importing `from pyspark.sql import Row` and then doing `df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(list_rows)` will give you the DataFrame.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am sendig  row by row from client to server by streaming. Then server received row and store to hbase table.   so i can not convert this into dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note:* This is not really an answer, but I don't understand as to what OP is asking about. Writing this in comment section would not have been possible, but may be we can take it forward from here.

OP says that he/she receives an RDD (purportedly a single element) from Client -

```
["Row(Moid=2, Tripid='11', Tstart='2007-05-28 08:53:14.040', Tend='2007-05-28 08:53:16.040', Xstart='9738.73', Ystart='103.246', Xend='9743.73', Yend='114.553')"]
```

Now, OP wants to translate that to a DataFrame. To translate that, one has to de-string the `Row` object, but OP has to clarify what he needs.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
rdd_from_client = [Row(Moid=2, Tripid='11', Tstart='2007-05-28 08:53:14.040', Tend='2007-05-28 08:53:16.040', Xstart='9738.73', Ystart='103.246', Xend='9743.73', Yend='114.553')]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_from_client)
df.show(truncate=False)
+----+-----------------------+------+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|Moid|Tend                   |Tripid|Tstart                 |Xend   |Xstart |Yend   |Ystart |
+----+-----------------------+------+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|2   |2007-05-28 08:53:16.040|11    |2007-05-28 08:53:14.040|9743.73|9738.73|114.553|103.246|
+----+-----------------------+------+-----------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```